# Automatically additionally save a .pdf of every notebook saved as .nb

Tags: files-and-directories, pdf-format, configuration

Is it possible to configure Mathematica to automatically save a .pdf of every notebook saved as .nb?
If it matters: I am using Mathematica 11 on Windows 10.

Comment: `Map[Export[StringReplace[#, ".nb"->".pdf"], Import[#]]&, FileNames["*.nb", dir]]` might do it if that's all you need

Comment: b3m2a1: Thanks, I guess that command when executed from a notebook does what I want to achieve retroactively. However, I'd prefer a solution that does this automatically every time I save a notebook (via ctrl+s or through the menu). Can I place this line or a similar one somewhere in a config file or the like so this command is executed in the current "work directory" every time a notebook is saved?

Comment: You can do that but it'll be super slow

Comment: How can I achieve this?